# Cron job not working properly; What is wrong or other methods?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

Ok, I have been trying to work this cron job for a whole day and no advancement on that part.
I have put in several code into Terminal(MAC) what everyone says on this website, but none of them work.
The code which I have seen the most is:

```
* * * * * php /usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /path/to/file/
```

or others something along those lines. However, none of them work.

Is there something wrong with the code? If so, please point it out.

If there isn't, I am done with cron job.
I have found another php script which one can write to insert data into MYSQL table every second, but I don't think this one works either.

```
<?php
    $start = microtime(true);
    set_time_limit(60);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 59; ++$i) {
        doMyThings();
        time_sleep_until($start + $i + 1);
    }
?>
```

Is this code right?
Is there any other methods I could use (written in php script like above) which you know about?

Comment: The command `php /usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /path/to/file/` after the asterisks is what you'd normally run from the shell. If it doesn't work there, then it won't work as cron job either. The double `php` for example wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect:

```
* * * * * php /usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /path/to/file/
          ^^^--php executable
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---script to run
```

You're telling php to run itself. The cron line should be simply:

```
* * * * * executable arguments
```

e.g.

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php  /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: cron usually emails any output from the job to the user owning the job. or just have your script do somethign to tell you it's finished, like writing something out to a file.

Comment: Can you write a code for me because I do not know how to write a code to distinguish if it wrote when I refreshed it or when the cronjob ran the script.

Comment: it still does not work for some reason. It only inserts the data into the table after I refresh

Comment: like mario said above: what you put into cron is basically exactly what you'd type into the command line, so log in as whatever user you want this job run as, and type in the command line yourself, and see what happens.

Comment: That is what I did. I logged onto the server and I typed it in, but does not work. It says No such file or directory for /usr/bin/php, but I thought that was the php executable so there doesn't have to be a file

Comment: my stuff was just an example. you need to adjust it to conform to YOUR server.

Comment: who do you find out the php executable

Comment: Found it! Thank you very much

Comment: One more question: Does * * * * * mean the 0th second of every minute or every minute from the second you execute the command?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the -f flag to explicitly  tell PHP run this script

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/script.php
```

Many people forget, cron has almost no enviroment variables, especially no $PATH .. so commands must have full file path to work..   eg;

```
php -f ./myscript.php
```

will work from a command line, but not from cron. To run from cron it needs full paths on both..

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/mydir/myscript.php
```

Comment: I got the part where cron needs full paths on both, but why do you need -f?

Comment: Why do you need to tell cron to explicitly when the path to the file is clearly written out

Comment: Because PHP says so..
    #php --help
     -f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.

but yes.. it isn't neccesary